# Regex to exclude same-digit delimited phone numbers excludes all phone numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been working with a regex expression:

```
/^(\d)(?!\1{2}\1{3}\1{4}$)\d{2}\d{3}\d{4}$/
```

which excludes a 10-digit phone number with all digits the same, for example, `2222222222` or `3333333333`.

Now, I need the regex to exclude same-digit phone numbers formatted like `222-222-2222` or `333-333-3333`.

This is the modified regex I tried in order to allow for the delimiters:

```
/^\((\d)(?!\1{2}-\1{3}-\1{4}$)\d{2}\)\d{3}-\d{4}$/
```

Unfortunately, it excludes *all* phone numbers. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Are you constrained to using a regex?  Because this would be easier and more flexible with other JS techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^(?:(?:(\d)(?!\1)){3}-?){2}(?:(?:(\d)(?!\1)){4})$/
```

I prefer regexr.com for testing.

Explaination:

```
(?:(?:(\d)(?!\1)){3}-?)
```

A group of 3 digits, but only if they're not repeats.  A single '-' at the end is optional.

The above two patterns must match twice.  The last pattern is the same except it matches 4 digits, and doesn't allow for a '-' at the end.

Edited to fix the 11 and 12 digit matching problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this regex also allows 11 and 12 digit phone numbers with the formats `xxxx-xxx-xxxx` and `xxxx-xxxx-xxxx`. It also doesn't allow for `(` and `)` like in `(xxx)-xxx-xxxx` or `(xxx)xxx-xxxx`. To be honest though, this is not clear in the question, as the examples specify `xxx-xxx-xxxx` whilst the regex looks like it's meant for either `(xxx)xxx-xxxx` or `(xxx)-xxx-xxxx` or both.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close with your delimiter version. Roughly speaking<sup>*</sup>, you were just missing a `)` in your lookahead and the first `-` in the actual match. (As an aside, the first `$` is also redundant.)

Assuming you wish to allow both `123-456-7890` *and* `(123)-456-7890`, the working<sup>*</sup> regex is:

<sub>**Regex 1**</sub>

```
^\(?(\d)(?!\1{2}\)?-\1{3}-\1{4})\d{2}\)?-\d{3}-\d{4}$
   |            |_|                    ||_
   |             |                     |  |
   |   missed (optional) ')'           | missed '-'
   |                                   |
 '?' required to make '(' and ')' optional
```

[Demo](//regex101.com/r/7kEjXm/3)

---

If you wish to allow `1234567890` and `(123)4567890` as well, you need to make the hyphens optional. Note that in the actual match, you have to "link" the two hypens by using a capturing group and back reference, otherwise `123-4567890`, `123456-7890`, etc, will also be matched:

<sub>**Regex 2**</sub>

```
^\(?(\d)(?!\1{2}\)?-?\1{3}-?\1{4})\d{2}\)?(-)?\d{3}\2\d{4}$
                    |      |              |__|     ||
                 optional hypens           |   back reference to captured hypen
                                           |
                                 optional captured hypen
```

---

**<sup>*</sup>Caveat:**

Both `(123-456-7890` & `123)-456-7890` (and `(1234567890` & `123)4567890` for the second regex) are allowed. If you wish to exclude these, the positive lookahead, `(?=\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}[^)])`, is required at the start of the regexes:

<sub>**Regex 1a**</sub>

```
^(?=\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}[^)])\(?(\d)(?!\1{2}\)?-\1{3}-\1{4})\d{2}\)?-\d{3}-\d{4}$
 |_____________________||_________________________________________________|
            |                                    |
   positive lookahead                         Regex 1
```

<sub>**Regex 2a**</sub>

```
^(?=\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}[^)])\(?(\d)(?!\1{2}\)?-?\1{3}-?\1{4})\d{2}\)?(-)?\d{3}\2\d{4}$
 |_____________________||_______________________________________________________|
            |                                       |
   positive lookahead                            Regex 2
```

<sub>**positive lookahead**</sub>

```
^(?=\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}[^)])
    |_______| |_______|
        |         |
        |  or starts with 3 digits, then no ")"
        |
Either starts with "(", then 3 digits, then ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

To match a 10 digit phone number phonenumber but exclude when they are all the same digits like `2222222222` or `222-222-2222` you might change you regex to:

[`^(\d)(?!\1{9})(?!\1{2}-\1{3}-\1{4})\d{2}(-?)\d{3}\2\d{4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/hrfPtM/1)

**Explanation**

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- Match the first digit in a capturing group `(\d)`
- A negative lookahead which asserts that what follows is not the same digit 9 times `(?!\1{9})`
- A negative lookahead which asserts that what follows is not the pattern with hypens `(?!\1{2}-\1{3}-\1{4})`
- Match the digits with or without a hyphen by using a backreference to the second group `\d{2}(-?)\d{3}\2\d{4}`
- The end of the string `$`

If you would like to also accept a format like (123)-456-7890 you could for example use:

[`^(?!(\d)\(\1{3}\))(?!(\d)\2{9})(?!(\d)\3{2}-\3{3}-\3{4})(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})(-?)?\d{3}\4\d{4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/tz30hZ/1)